# How to count number of peaks in graph ? -graph analysis-

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this curve that contains certain peaks - I want to know how to get the number of these peaks.

**Sample Data:**

```
0.10    76792
0.15    35578
0.20    44675
0.25    52723
0.30    27099
0.35    113931
0.40    111043
0.45    34312
0.50    101947
0.55    100824
0.60    20546
0.65    114430
0.70    113764
0.75    15713
0.80    83133
0.85    79754
0.90    17420
0.95    121094
1.00    117346
1.05    22841
1.10    95095
1.15    94999
1.20    18986
1.25    111226
1.30    106640
1.35    34781
1.40    66356
1.45    68706
1.50    21247
1.55    117604
1.60    114268
1.65    26292
1.70    88486
1.75    89841
1.80    49863
1.85    111938
```

The 1st column is the X values, the 2nd column is the y values.

I want to write a macro or formula that tell me how many peaks in this graph.

Note: this graph is actualy ploted and exported from matlab, so if there is a way i can tell my code to do it for me from matlab it would be also great!

Comment: There are quite a few matlab peak detectors, see the [Mathworks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=peak)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if your data was in `A1:B36` then this formula
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B35>B1:B34),--(B2:B35>B3:B36))`
returns 11 peaks

It checks if

- `B2` is higher than `B1` and B3, if so counts it as a peak
- then if `B3` is higher than `B2` and `B4`, if so counts it as a peak and so on

[image]

**[Updated: VBA request added]**

```
Sub GetMax()
    Dim chr As ChartObject
    Dim chrSeries As Series
    Dim lngrow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set chr = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    Set chrSeries = chr.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If chrSeries Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For lngrow = 2 To UBound(chrSeries.Values) - 1
        If chrSeries.Values(lngrow) > chrSeries.Values(lngrow - 1) Then
            If chrSeries.Values(lngrow) > chrSeries.Values(lngrow + 1) Then
                chrSeries.Points(lngrow).ApplyDataLabels
                With chrSeries.Points(lngrow).DataLabel
                    .Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
                    .Border.Color = 1
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing answer, i really appreciate it, but is it possible to have graph pointing at peaks too like in your example ??

Comment: I have another question arround same topic :) !,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994141/how-to-extract-and-plot-only-minimal-and-maximal-peaks-of-an-array-graph-anal

Comment: the explanation totally makes sense, however when I try that Excel (2010) complains about the formula. (formula error) - Any clue?