# How to extract and plot only minimal and maximal peaks of an array , -graph analysis- With Matlab or excel

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I'm doing video analysis.
The end result array I get is something like:

```
signal =

    Columns 1 through 7

       73960       73960       73960       73960       68102       68102       68102

  Columns 8 through 14

       68102       19187       19187       19187       19187       14664       14664

  Columns 15 through 21

       14664       14664       13715       13715       13715       13715       30832

  Columns 22 through 28

       30832       30832       30832       53031       53031       53031       53031

  Columns 29 through 35

       56897       56897       56897       16104       16104       16104       16104

  Columns 36 through 42

       15188       15188       15188       15188       13973       13973       13973
```

Note: actual array I get is usually 600+

So when I plot this I get very bad looking graph, so I want to filter this array and only keep the ** maximal and minimal peaks** local maxima and minima so that the graph would have nicer waves

Is there a way I can do it with MATLAB?

if not then can I do it with excel? 
as I usually save this array to excel sheet Like this

```
0.1 68102
0.15    19187
0.2 14664
0.25    13715
0.3 30832
0.35    53031
0.4 56897
0.45    16104
0.5 15188
0.55    13973
0.6 21437
0.65    66950
0.7 65356
0.75    22562
0.8 14154
0.85    13938
0.9 20692
0.95    72823
1   69975
1.05    15328
1.1 14494
1.15    13681
1.2 14205
1.25    65278
1.3 63055
1.35    16999
1.4 14050
1.45    14245
```

In which the 1st column is the time(y-axis) and 2nd column is the amplitude.(x-axis)

I use this formula to count local maxima (Thanks to **brettdj** from stackoverflow.com)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B149>B1:B148),--(B2:B149>B3:B150))
```

And this formula to count local minima

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B149<B1:B148),--(B2:B149<B3:B150))
```

But what I need is to filter the array to only keep local maxima and local minima so I can get nicely drawn curve without noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum and minimum values just use:

```
[sig_min, idx_min] = min(signal);
[sig_max, idx_max] = max(signal);
```

But I couldnt understand exactly what you want… since my account is new, I cant comment on your question to try to understand it better.

— edit 1:

Ok, now I understand what you want. I don't know why you have this array with repetitive numbers, but supposing you don't want them, or, at least, that is better to remove them to find local maxima and minima, you should do:

```
sinal_norep = signal(find(diff(sinal)));
```

where signal_norep will be your new array containing only values that differs from the last one:

[image: On the left is your signal, on the right the new one]

Now we can search for the index where occurs local maxima and minima on this array, by doing:

```
minimas_idx = find(signal_norep(2:end-1)<signal_norep(1:end-2) & signal_norep(2:end-1)<signal_norep(3:end))+1;
maximas_idx = find(signal_norep(2:end-1)>signal_norep(1:end-2) & signal_norep(2:end-1)>signal_norep(3:end))+1;
```

And their values:

```
signal_maximas = signal_norep(maximas_idx);
signal_minimas = signal_norep(minimas_idx);
```

Thats it x)

Comment: i dont want min and max value in the array, i want the local minima and maxima (the peak of the curve) peak of curve when you plot it on a graph i mean

Comment: The peak is defined if its More than the value before and after (the)

Answer (score 3):

This VBA

- Reads the data from column A and B into a variant arrays
- Find the local minima and maxima and extracts that to second array
- Creates a brand new chart of the minima/maximia (see image)

[image]

```
     Sub NewGraph()
    Dim X
    Dim Y
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim Chr As ChartObject

    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))
    Y = Application.Transpose(X)

    For lngRow = 2 To UBound(X, 1) - 1
        If X(lngRow, 2) > X(lngRow - 1, 2) Then
            If X(lngRow, 2) > X(lngRow + 1, 2) Then
                lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
                Y(2, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 2)
            End If
        Else
            If X(lngRow, 2) < X(lngRow + 1, 2) Then
                lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
                Y(2, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next lngRow

    ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt)

    Set Chr = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(250, 175, 275, 200)
    With Chr.Chart

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = Application.Index(Application.Transpose(Y), 0, 1)
            .Values = Application.Index(Application.Transpose(Y), 0, 2)
        End With
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just write a simple loop over the array in Matlab to achieve this. I don't see any fundamental problems there?

If you don't want loops in Matlab, you can do it with some array operations. If you have two equallly long arrays a and b, you can do something like c = a>b, which gives you a list with ones and zeros. You1 can use this as a oneliner for selecting the maxima/minima.
Zo suppose you have an upshifted and downshifted array b, c. Such that (except at endpoints)
b(n-1)=a(n)=c(n+1). You can get an array containing only the extrema and zeros by `q=a.*( (a>b).*(a>c) + (a<b).*(a<c) )`

One advise: If you signal has noise, than also this selection will be noisy. To smoothen the function, you should apply some kind of moving averaging with a kernel you like.

Comment: i dont want min and max value in the array, i want the local minima and maxima (the peak of the curve) peak of curve when you plot it on a graph i mean

Comment: So, you can easily identify them by the loop right? Also by have 3 arrays, one upshifted (b), one downshifted (c), you have the local peaks by in Matlab performing a.*(a>b).*(a>c). So you will get the extrema and zeros everywhere else.