# In pure Excel, how to reference a column in a range (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have on a sheet a range of numbers, from that range, how can I reference a full column or row given by index ?

I am using 2007.. I looked into HLookup/Vlookup/Index without success

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean referencing the whole column/row as a range/array in another formula?

If so, the only way i can think of would be to use `OFFSET`

```
=OFFSET($A:$A,,MyColIndex-1)
=OFFSET($1:$1,MyRowIndex-1,)
```

thats...

```
=OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,[height],[width])
```

However this won't work if you insert a column to the left of A, or a row above 1.

EDIT: just found a way around that little problem...

```
=OFFSET($A:$A,,MyColIndex-Column($A:$A))
=OFFSET($1:$1,MyRowIndex-Row($1:$1),)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can convert your range to a table, then you can use structured references to refer to columns in your table.

Example

- your table is called `Table1` and has columns `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`
- cell `E1` has the name of a column (e.g. `Column1`)

In this case, you can calculate (for instance) the sum of the column specified by E1 with:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Table1["& E1 &"]"))
```

Comment: In case you're not familiar with them, tables are like lists, but improved. In Excel 2007, Selecting a range and pressing `Ctrl-L` now creates a table instead of a list.

Comment: Good call on the table but you don't need to use indirect.  You can just use =SUM(Table1[Header1]) where Header1 is the column header title.  Indirect is best avoided if possible.

Comment: Jesse, that will work if you can hardcode Header1 into the formula.

However, if you want to specify the column based on the value of some other cell, I only know how to do it using `INDIRECT`...

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:1048576,0,2))
```

This sums the entire 2nd column in the specified range, i.e., B2:B1048576.  It works because a 0 in the row argument of the index function returns the entire column - within the range specified.  The following would sum just B2:B3:

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:3,0,2))
```

... and this would sum C2:C3

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:F3,0,2))
```

Comment: +1 nicely done. The `Index` function is handy for the same application on VBA arrays.

Comment: @brettdj, I didn't know that.  That could be very handy.

Comment: Doug, I used this technique in http://stackoverflow.com/q/8994141/641067 to take two slices through a variant array.