# How to find minimum of each curvature point?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve

I'm using Polynomial curve fitting to analyze my data (polyfit and polyval) and i got the curve like this. I want to find the minimum point of each curve (red dot). If i use min() i will get the point only one curve. How to get both point?

[image: Cure Fitting]

Thnak you so much

Comment: You could use [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) using your signal with `minus (-)` or could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994141/how-to-extract-and-plot-only-minimal-and-maximal-peaks-of-an-array-graph-anal/8994913#8994913) where I created a very basic local minima script.

Comment: That may be offtopic, sorry for that, but your fit seems everything but right. Are you sure you should use polynomials to fit? Couldn't you get better results with cubic-spline-interpolation?

Comment: Agree with @thewaywewalk.... why are you even fitting? Not fitting would be better than what I see in the image posted. In any case, I believe there is a function `findpeaks` which might help you.

Comment: Invert the data and then apply findpeaks

Comment: @thewaywewalk & Try Hard, My mostly data look like what you saw in the graph and i want only the data on the right curve so someone advice me to using curve fitting to seperate it. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @BowHouse just use spline interpolation instead of polynomials and it will solve your problem. You can then also apply findpeaks the same way.

Comment: @thewaywewalk ok, thankyou i will try like you said.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
% Your polynomial coefficients
c = [-1 4 5 2 6 2 4 5];

% Find real roots of its derivative
R = roots( [numel(c)-1 : -1 : 1] .* c(1:end-1) );
R = R(imag(R)==0);

% Compute and sort function values of these extrema
if ~isempty(R)

    [yExtrema, indsExtrema] = sort(polyval(c, R));
    xExtrema = R(indsExtrema);

    % Extract the two smallest ones
    yMins = yExtrema(1:2);
    xMins = xExtrema(1:2);

else
    yMins = [];
    xMins = [];

end
```